# how to get a UTC offset from a timezone in js

Tags: javascript

In Vanilla JavaScript (i.e. **without using Moment.js**).

I have a server returning a timezone string, like `Asia/Tokyo` `America/New_York` etc...
That timezone is independent from the user current timezone. So the server can return `Asia/Tokyo` when my current OS timezone is `America/New_York`

from the server given timezone, I would like to format it to something like =>

`UTC+09:00 Asia/Tokyo`

So in simple, I just want, from a given timezone, to find the UTC Offset of that timezone.

There is a native function `getTimezoneOffset` in JS, but I can't find a `setTimezone`

I tried to do something like

```
var d = new Date()
new Date(d.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo' })).getTimezoneOffset()
```

but this always return my current offset.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Timezone is independent of the current timezone? can you elaborate?

Comment: Native JavaScript APIs don't have support for any timezone other than the local one (i.e. whatever the user has set their OS to) and UTC.

Comment: @its4zahoor basically if I am in america/newYork, and the server give `Asia/Tokyo` I want to have the offset of `Asia/Tokyo` based on UTC and not on my current timezone (america/newYork)

Comment: @JoachimSauer so you say I can only get the utcoffset of my localtimezone to UTC, but I can't get the offset of all the other (still supported by date) timezone to UTC ?

Comment: @Bobby: I'm no JavaScript expert, but from looking at the `Date` API, I don't see any support for specifying (or querying) any other time zones. What makes you think others are "still supported by date"?

Comment: well the fact that you can get timezone, getUTC diff from your current timezone, and converting to a timezone using `toLocaleString` make me thing it's just missing feature. the timezone are supported there is just not implementation for this.

Comment: @Bobby: oh, I see, yes. The support for TimeZones is certainly incomplete. Getting date/time APIs correct with all the messiness is hard any many languages get it wrong in the first attempt (Java for example needed 3 attempts to get it right with `java.time`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to calculate this, this solution is slightly hacky, since we're formatting a date, then parsing. But it should do what you wish.

I'm converting to the "sv" date format, since it's very similar to ISO-8601, then parsing to get the UTC date.

Note: The offset will be negative for timezones east of the Greenwich meridian, this is the same as the IANA convention. You can simply reverse if you wish to get UTC offset as minutes *ahead* of UTC.
Also, I'm rounding at then end, since our original date will contain a millisecond component that we're not interested in.

```js
function getUTCOffset(date, timeZone) {
    const dateComponents = date.toLocaleString("sv", { timeZone }).split(/[\-\s:]/);
    // Months are zero-based in JavaScript
    dateComponents[1] = dateComponents[1] - 1;
    const utcDate = Date.UTC(...dateComponents);
    return Math.round((date - utcDate) / 60 / 1000);
}

console.log(getUTCOffset(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo'));
console.log(getUTCOffset(new Date(), 'America/Los_Angeles'));
```

Comment: I see, yeah a bit patchy, but I guess it works and apparently native date can't do much better.

Thank you

Comment: I think this is about the only way to to this in native JavaScript, I'm not aware of any others!

Comment: Keep in mind that the offset calculated this way depends on the current time of year and can change due to daylight saving time. If this is used for indication in the UI, it can be confusing to the user. And if it's used for any other functionality, it can cause ugly bugs.

Comment: That's a good point, @JoachimSauer, the UTC offset will vary if the timezone in question uses DST.